# SQL - implement like nested loops in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns table like shown below

```
------------------------------------------
ID .     | Value                          |
------------------------------------------
1 .      | A1
         | B1
         | C1
2 .      | A2
         | B2
         | C2
         | D2
         | E2
-------------------------------------------
```

Want to query the above table and Expected Results: Input to the query  is where id=1 and id=2

```
-----------------------
Results
-----------------------
A1 A2
A1 B2
A1 C2
A1 D2
A1 E2 
B1 A2
B1 B2
B1 C2
B1 D2
B1 E2
C1 A2
C1 B2
C1 C2
C1 D2
C1 E2  
----------------------------------------------
```

Your input is highly appreciated. TIA.

and expecting results as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuDEb.png)

Could please share some example to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: you should formulate logic of what you are trying to implement - presented example by itself just makes no sense (at least to me)

Comment: logic is still absent and example still makes no sense - as well as Impaler's and Himanshu's answers - just answers in sake of answering o(

Answer (score 1):

A simple cross join should get what you get:

```
select
  concat(a.value, b.value) as results
from my_table a
cross join my_table b
where a.id = 1
  and b.id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks,  The Impaler. I appreciate your comments.  The above query would return all values of "a.value" and "b.value".  My need is for every a.value, concatenate with every b.value.

Comment: @Nagaraj Fixed as requested, using the `CONCAT()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Select a.value, b.value
  From table a full outer join
 Table b on a.value<b.value
 where a.id=1 and b.id=1
```